# Python - Get paragraph text (Web Scraping)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I get text from a paragraph before break tags like:

```
      <p align="right">
        <font size="3">
             ABC
         <br/>
             DEF
         <br/>
             FGH
         <br/>
             iJK
        </font>
      </p>
```

and save in an array like:

```
text[0] = "ABC"
text[1] = "DEF"
text[2] = "iJK"
```

I am currently using:

```
paragraph_text = soup.find('p')
print paragraph_text.text
```

But it will give me all the text of a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the `p` element and iterate over the [`.stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings):

```
for text in soup.p.stripped_strings:
    print(text)
```

Prints:

```
ABC
DEF
FGH
iJK
```

---

Or, if you want a list:

```
texts = list(soup.p.stripped_strings)
print(texts)
```

Prints:

```
['ABC', 'DEF', 'FGH', 'iJK']
```